# Data is not saving in db using generic repository and Entity Framework 5.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, repository

I've created application asp.net using a generic repository and Entity Framework.
The abstract class has this code:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class 
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Edit(T entity);
    void Save();
}
```

and the `GenericRepository` class contains the following code:

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<C, T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class where C : DbContext, new() 
{
    private C _entities = new C();

    public C Context {
        get { return _entities; }
        set { _entities = value; }
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll() {
        IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>();
        return query;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) {
        IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
        return query;
    }

    public virtual void Add(T entity) {
        _entities.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity) {
        _entities.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Edit(T entity) {
        _entities.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Save() {
        _entities.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Now I want to create class for each of my database tables to save the data.

Here is the code for one of my database tables:

```
public class AmountDLL : GenericRepository<HMSEntities, Tbl_Amount>
{
    //:Base<Tbl_Amount>

    public override void Add(Tbl_Amount entity)
    {
        base.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

At last I have tried to add data through front end on button click

```
 protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        AmountDLL amtdll = new AmountDLL();
        Tbl_Amount tblamt = new Tbl_Amount();
        tblamt.Amt_Type = txt_amt_type.Text;
        tblamt.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            tblamt.IsActive = true;
        }
        else
        { 
            tblamt.IsActive = false;
        }

        amtdll.Add(tblamt);
    }
```

When I run the application, it worked fine, but it did not save the data in the table.

Please check and suggest any changes

Comment: I don't see any call to `.SaveChanges()`

Comment: I think you need to call SaveChanges method after adding

Comment: You should learn how Entity Framework works before trying to create a useless repository hiding it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Entity Framework for every entity to save the data either it's insert, update or delete, we call the [`SaveChanges()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on instance of that entity.

In your case you need to call the `Save()` method for persisting to database which you have defined in your repository class for that which abstracts the `SaveChanges()` call to your respective Entity type:

```
amtdll.Add(tblamt);
amtdll.Save();  // this needs to be called.
```